# git push error on Mac computer

Tags: git

On my Mac computer, when I typed in: git push -u origin master
I received the following error message:

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Valeries-MacBook-Air:code valerielee$

How can I correct this error?

Comment: do u have the git repository?

Answer (score 1):

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)`

This means your current working directory is not within a git repository.

Change directories to a git repository and then run:

`git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you simply created a `.git` directory (based on the small CLI example you posted above). The correct way to create new git repository (even for existing code) is to issue a `git init` command first.

The answer given by Chris is of course correct then. At the risk of sounding patronizing, I would also like to recommend that you take a look at some tutorials. Here are two I consider great for my students:

- http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/
- http://try.github.io/

Hope that helps.